# Render one component several times in different html pages with different text

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm new to react and I'm trying to render one component in different html files (because I'm working in an existing project), each of them with different text.
I'm thinking of something like this:

```
class ctaSection extends React.Component{

   render(){
       return(
           <div className="cta-section">
           <div className="md:w-9c">
               <h5 className="uppercase">{this.props.h5}</h5>
               <h3>{this.props.h3}</h3>
           </div>
           <div className="cta-button">
               <a href="#">
                   <button className="w-full">{this.props.button}</button>
               </a>
           </div>
       </div>
       );
   }

}

export default ctaSection;
```

Then, in my index.js, I'm rendering like this, passing the props:

```
let ctaPage1 = document.getElementById('cta-section-page-1');
let ctaPage2 = document.getElementById('cta-section-page-2');
ReactDOM.render(<CtaSection h3='my text for page 1' h5='my h5 for page 1' button='hello'/>, ctaPage1);
 ReactDOM.render(<CtaSection h3='text for page 2' h5='something' button='click me'/>, ctaPage2);
```

I'm not sure if this is the best and simpler way to do this, because I'm calling ReactDOM.render twice for same component, and I got this error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.
```

This works fine if I render the component once, but not for multiple instances. 
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure how React works with multiple html pages, but it doesn't look like your index.js file knows which html page it's on, so one of those document.getElementByIds is going to not find anything. I'm assuming that each of those elements are on different pages.

Answer (score 0):

I've thought about this more, and I'm not experienced with adding React to existing websites, but here's what I'd suggest:

I would have 1 JS file per HTML page that imports *CtaSection*, each of those files would look like such:

```
// page1.js
import CtaSection from '../CtaSection'; // or wherever it is

let ctaPage = document.getElementById('cta-section-page');
ReactDOM.render(<CtaSection h3='my text for page 1' h5='my h5 for page 1' button='hello'/>, ctaPage);
```

You would just need to make sure each html page uses the corresponding JS file.

```
// page1.html 
<body>
    <div id="cta-section-page"></div>
    <script src="page1.js"></script>
</body>
```

Repeat for each page.

Comment: yes, I think that was my error, adding the reactDOM.render to the same index.js file twice, because this file was my only entrypoint for js in my webpack config... However adding it to different js files solves the problem, thank you